# Primefaces Accordion: actionListener mapped to remoteCommand not called anymore

Tags: primefaces

"anymore" is definitely a key word here.  I had this working, and even after comparing my previous revisions, I cannot see a smoking gun.

I have placed an accordion in the navigation panel on the West side of my layout.  I have overridden the actionListener to call a remoteCommand, like this.

```
<p:accordionPanel widgetVar="tabPanel"
                    dynamic="true" cache="true"
                    activeIndex="-1"
                    actionListener="tabChange()">

        <p:remoteCommand  name="tabChange"
              process="@this"
              update=":contentPanel"
              actionListener="#{viewSelectionBean.changeView}" />
```

When clicking on any given tab, it used to call the backing bean method changeView, which sets the html page being shown in ":contentPanel", but now I get no backing bean action.  I have commandLinks within each of these accordion tabs that also call changeView successfully.  Its only the tabChange() that doesn't seem to be called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actionListener is not a property of accordionPanel, therefore, thats why it wouldn't be called.  This feature can be made to work using ajax, but it demonstrates lag while expanding each tab.  Lag aside, one might also have success overriding onTabChange of the accordionPanel, but that will force you to have to manually effect the activeIndex, and the expanding of tabs.

```
<p:accordionPanel widgetVar="tabPanel"
                    dynamic="true" cache="true"
                    activeIndex="-1">

   <p:ajax event="tabChange"
                listener="#{viewSelectionBean.onTabChange}"
                update=":contentPanel"
                process="@this"
                partialSubmit="true"/>
```